# Meaning of „einen alles“ in a sentence

Tags: pronoun, indefinite-pronoun

I am not sure what the meaning of "*einen alles*" is in the following sentence:

> Es mutet **einen alles** an, als wäre man bei einer alten Frau.

My guess is that “*einen alles*” means each and every person, where *alles* is used to emphasise the pronoun *einer*. Or should “*einen alles*” be taken together with a meaning like "one and all"?

Source: https://www.dwds.de/wb/anmuten

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clause that starts with the conjunction *»als«* just gives a comparing description of the main clause, which grammatically also could stand alone (but of course semantically makes more sense when combined with the *als*-clause).

> Es mutet einen alles an.

The first word in this sentence is an expletive *es* that is there only to allow the verb to still be at position 2 although any "real" parts of speech are somewhere behind the verb. But you also can move one of these "real" parts of speech onto position 1, which will cause the placeholder *»es«* to disappear:

> 1. Einen mutet alles an.
> 2. Alles mutet einen an.

The word *an* must stay at the end, because it is the prefix of the separable verb *anmuten,* and when separable verbs are separated, the prefix must be at the very end of the clause. But in a German sentence anything that is not a verb can stand at position 1.

But which of both words that are not part of the verb *anmuten* is the subject?
It can't be *einen,* because the subject is always in nominative case, but *einen* is in accusative case, so it must be an object, and the only solution is, that *alles* (everything) is the subject.

So, we have for now:

- Subject = *alles* (everything)
- Verb = *anmuten* (to seem, to appear)
- Subordinate clause = *"als" + Konjunktiv* ("as" + subjunctive)

And in English this is enough to build a sentence:

> Everything seems, as ...

So, what is *einen* for? You need this accusative object, because the verb *anmuten* feels much better when used together with an accusative object. This is ok:

> Alles mutet an, als ...

But this is much better:

> Alles mutet **einen** an, als ...

And what's that in English?

> Everything seems **to one,** as ...

The word *einen* (to one) describes the beneficiary or sufferer of the action. Who will feel sad or happy as consequence of the action? In German we love to add this information to sentences. Most often we do this with free dative objects, but in your example it is an accusative object. Adding who is affected by the action is not so common in English sentences, and often it's even impossible:

> Es tut mir sehr leid, aber ich habe leider den Hut verloren, den du mir geliehen hast. Der Wind blies **mir** deinen Hut von meinem Kopf.
> I'm very sorry, but I'm afraid I lost the hat you lent me. The wind blew your hat off my head.

Here in the English translation you can say that it was your hat and my head, but in English it is impossible to say with just one word that I suffered from this loss at the moment when it happened. But we love to add this information, and that's why we have additional grammatical features that allow us to easily add such information. The dative free object *mir* in the hat example is one such feature, and the optional accusative object of *anmuten* is another example of a grammatical feature that only serves to tell who can feel sad or happy about the action.

---

With the expletive at position 1 the sentence even becomes so strange in English that it must be called *wrong*, but in German this is the preferred construction:

> Es mutet einen alles an, als ...
> It seems everything to one, as ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The versions without the expletive *es* are rarely used by native speakers. German native speakers prefer the version starting with *es,* also in other sentences: *»Es waren viele Leute im Bus«* is preferred over *»Viele Leute waren im Bus.«* I mentioned the sentences without *es* for didactical reasons, to make it easier to find the subject. So, since we don't often use the *es*-less sentences, it's hard to tell if they mean the same or not. But for the frequently used form with the expletive *es* I can say, that both meanings are possible, depending on the context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. No. There are different types of expletive *es* in German grammar, but German has no other expletive word than *es.* English has an expletive *it: "It rains."* and an expletive *there: "There is a hair in my soup."* But in German you have only *es*, either as subject-expletive ("Es regnet", "Es gibt Spaghetti") or as "Vorfeld-Expletiv" ("Es ist ein Haar in meiner Suppe"). If you want more information please consult [this page](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=expletive) or click or tab [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: This discussion is off-topic here. If consulting other questions and answers doesn't help you, please ask a new proper question [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The topic is *»Meaning of „einen alles“ in a sentence«.* You have a question about expletive pronouns which is a different topic and the answer to your question would be too long to fit in just one comment. So please aks a proper question. This is what stackexchange was made for: Asking questions and answering them. It is not made to discuss in comments.

Answer (score 6):

The words *einen alles* do not constitute a single part of the sentence. These words simply happen to be adjacent.

*Einen* is the accusative object. *Alles* is the (true) subject. The *es* at the beginning of the sentence is only a placeholder, to allow for the subject to appear later in the sentence.

So the sententence above is equivalent to the following:

> Alles mutet einen an, als wäre man bei einer alten Frau.